# R graph quality

Tags: r, pdf, graph, plot

Is there a way to optimize the graph quality from R?

I have 30 million data points, and I generated a [Q–Q plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) and saved it as a PDF file using:

```
pdf(myPlot.pdf)
qqnorm(X)
dev.off()
```

But the PDF file size is so big that I can not even open it to view!

Is there a way either saving this with a lower quality or as a different type (I don't necessarily need PDF) so I can view the graph?

Comment: `pdf` is a vector format, so the pdf file viewer would try to render thise 30 million data points on the fly. Export to `png` that is a lossless data compression raster format.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options.

1. Don't plot all the points. Compare:

   ```
   X = rnorm(1e5)
   qqnorm(X, xlim=c(-4.5, 4.5), ylim=c(-4.5, 4.5))
   qqnorm(X[seq(1, length(X), 5)], xlim=c(-4.5, 4.5), ylim=c(-4.5, 4.5))
   qqnorm(X[seq(1, length(X), 10)], xlim=c(-4.5, 4.5), ylim=c(-4.5, 4.5))
   ```

   I would suggest it's almost impossible to visually notice a difference
2. Don't use the pdf plotting device. Instead try `png` or `jpeg`. These functions have a resolution argument, `res`, that controls the plotting resolution. So something like this should do the trick:

   ```
   ppi = 300
   png("mygraph.png", width=6*ppi, height=6*ppi, res=ppi)
   qqnorm(X)
   dev.off()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163640/how-to-reduce-size-of-r-plots-in-eps-format) very informative, mainly with respect to the options you don't have.

For sharing the plot, I would go with showing only a sufficiently large fraction of the points; this is the scope of a plot anyway, to provide a visual overview of the data, not to necessarily include all of them. For viewing only, I would pick the PNG format.